# how do i get query parameter in NextJs13 dynamic api routing

Tags: next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

i have tried a lot of different ways and i can't seem to get adequation documentation on this

I am try to to fetch this URL `/api/stripe/${sessionId}` to the server-side API path that looks like this
`api/stripe/[session]/route.js` and retrieve the sessionId to make a stripe call

````
import Stripe from "stripe";

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRETE_KEY);

export async function GET(req){
    
    const {sessionId} = NextRequest.nextUrl.searchParams
    console.log(sessionId)
  
    const checkoutSession = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(sessionId,
    
    )


     return NextResponse.json({checkoutSession})
}```
````